# Fail command start-domain glassfish3

Tags: glassfish

I am using ubuntu 12.4 and I installed glassfish3 follow this tutorial: http://www.marlonj.com/blog/2012/05/instalando-glassfish-3-1-2-en-ubuntu-server-12-04/

All is fine..but when I try to start a domain: sudo -u glassfish bin/asadmin start-domain domain1

show this error:

> Esperando a que se inicie domain1 ............Error al iniciar domain
>   domain1. El servidor ha finalizado de forma prematura con el código de
>   salida 0. Antes de terminar, ha generado la siguiente salida:
>
> Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
>   [#|2013-09-24T13:31:50.742-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|Running
>   GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (build
>   23)|#]
>
> [#|2013-09-24T13:31:51.819-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly
>   Framework 1.9.46 started in: 308ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]|#]
>
> [#|2013-09-24T13:31:51.819-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=31;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly
>   Framework 1.9.46 started in: 294ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]|#]
>
> [#|2013-09-24T13:31:51.819-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly
>   Framework 1.9.46 started in: 411ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]
>
> [#|2013-09-24T13:31:51.819-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly
>   Framework 1.9.46 started in: 402ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]|#]
>
> [#|2013-09-24T13:31:52.439-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|Registered
>   org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for
>   persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|#]
>
> [#|2013-09-24T13:31:52.659-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|GlassFish
>   Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (23) tiempo de inicio: Felix
>   (8.339ms), servicios de inicio(2.907ms), total(11.246ms)|#]
>
> [#|2013-09-24T13:31:52.660-0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|Cerrando
>   v3 debido a una excepción de inicio: No free port within range:
>   8080=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@6365c8|#]
>
> [#|2013-09-24T13:31:52.721-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-21;|Servidor
>   inactivo iniciado|#]
>
> [#|2013-09-24T13:31:52.723-0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-21;|Already
>   stopped, so just returning|#]
>
> Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "FelixStartLevel"
>
> Fallo del comando start-domain.

Any idea

Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your own domain instead of using default `domain1`. You can do this with:

```
 asadmin create-domain mydomain
 asadmin start-domain mydomain
```

Then you can access your domain by typing `localhost:4848` in your web browser.

I've done this using Windows and Glassfish4 and it worked fine, but I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading zip file, 
`cd/usr/local/glassfish4.1.1./bin`
`sudo ./asadmin`
`//try to create`
`asadmin> create-domain domain1`
`//if already exist`
`asadmin> start-domain domain1`